# BDD with 3rd party services

Tags: selenium, bdd, specflow

I am developing a asp.net mvc site that depends deeply on a 3rd party web service.

I would like to know what is the best approach to develop this site since the web service is not ready yet and I can't wait it to be ready to start developing.

I am using Specflow and selenium to drive my development.

Answer (score 2):

You can create mock response files of that web service and use them during development of your site. I assume that general structure of web service response is already established.

Comment: You mean, I can create interfaces representing these web services and implement them with mocks and after that just replace with the actual web services? Right? So, this means I would have to change the tests expectations also. Is this the best way?

Comment: No-no, it's much simpler.Suppose a webservice returns an XML document. WIth an actual working webservice you would write something like doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://webservice.com?user="Adam Smith"')) (code in Ruby using XML parsing library Nokogiri), and then manipulate variable doc. With mock response files you should just use something like doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.new(AdamSmith.xml)).

Comment: But in that case we are assuming that I know exactly how the web service will return the data which is not the case. What I know is what it has to return and I have model classes, I will have to map the service data to my model. So I can't just replace an xml.